# 2011 Chevy Malibu will not reverse

Tags: chevrolet, automatic-transmission, malibu

What does it mean when ur car won't reverse but the other gears work? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2):

It could mean

- There is a problem inside the transmission causing the reverse system not to work.  It could be a broken internal gear, or a problem in the hydraulic control system or any number of other failures.  The fix here is to replace the transmission.  Sorry big $$$ to fix.
- Its possible that there is a problem with the transmission control linkage between the shifter handle and the transmission.  I've seen troubles here with bent linkage rods (although that was a manual transmission).  I've also seen a cable operated system with a broken plastic bushing that caused the car to not shift correctly.  Easy, peasy $4 fix.  I will say on that car the owner had some notification of the trouble. The previous day, the car wouldn't start (as the neutral/park safety switch wasn't set correctly...)

Generally you may have some indications of troubles.  Loud clunk noises? Other odd transmission behavior?  Troubles with transmission fluid levels?  Excessive mileage ( greater than 185,000 or so) ?